How to enable Treesitter syntax highlighting in a Telescope previewer buffer
I am creating a plugin which creates a custom Telescope picker and it has a json preview buffer. I want that buffer to be nicely syntax highlighted using treesitter but its not working. I added following line but it introduces very minimal highight.
This is the code snippet for telescope picker
local function pick_board(json_data)
  local opts = {}
  pickers
      .new(opts, {
        prompt_title = "Boards",
        finder = finders.new_table({
          results = json_data,
          entry_maker = opts.entry_maker or boardentry_maker(opts),
        }),
        attach_mappings = function(prompt_bufnr, _)
          actions.select_default:replace(function()
            actions.close(prompt_bufnr)
            local selection = action_state.get_selected_entry()
            pick_framework(selection["value"]["data"])
          end)
          return true
        end,
        previewer = previewers.new_buffer_previewer({
          title = "Board Info",
          define_preview = function(self, entry, _)
            local json = utils.strsplit(vim.inspect(entry["value"]["data"]), "\n")
            local bufnr = self.state.bufnr
            vim.api.nvim_buf_set_lines(bufnr, 0, -1, false, json)
            vim.defer_fn(function()
              vim.api.nvim_buf_set_option(bufnr, 'wrap', true)
              vim.api.nvim_buf_set_option(bufnr, 'linebreak', true)
              vim.api.nvim_buf_set_option(bufnr, 'wrapmargin', 2)
              vim.treesitter.start(bufnr, 'json') -- This added minimal highlight
            end, 0)
          end,
        }),
        sorter = conf.generic_sorter(opts),
      })
      :find()
end

I have specifically added this line

vim.treesitter.start(bufnr, 'json')

The result
You can see following comparison with and without that line
Comparison
Treesitter can do way more syntax highlighting when you just open a json file like you can see here
wanted result
What changes should I make in code to make the json preview like that

I tried running your code and added
vim.api.nvim_buf_get_option(bufnr, 'filetype')
to print its value. The value was empty because I was adding JSON data from the variable.
I thought that’s what you meant to do, but the value of filetype was empty because it wasn’t recognized as a specific file type and was shown as text instead. After using the following line, I managed to get syntax highlighting:
vim.api.nvim_buf_set_option(bufnr, 'filetype', 'json')
